# TikZ calendar and ConTeXT

Tags: tikz-pgf, context, calendar

I'm trying to use the TikZ calendar package  in ConTeXT, but I'm not having luck. The problem is that before the months and days names appears the keyword **translation** between square brackets. How i can fix that?

the code:

```
\usemodule[tikz]
\usetikzlibrary[calendar]


\starttext

\tikz \calendar [dates=2012-01-01 to 2012-12-31,
month list, month label left,month yshift=1.25em]
if (Sunday) [black!50]
% GROUP 1
if (between=2012-08-09 and 2012-08-12)[orange]
if (between=2012-06-01 and 2012-06-03)[orange]
if (between=2012-04-05 and 2012-04-07)[orange]
if (between=2012-12-22 and 2012-12-27)[orange]
% GROUP 2
if (between=2012-09-10 and 2012-09-15)[blue] 
if (between=2012-08-17 and 2012-08-21)[blue] 
if (between=2012-06-29 and 2012-07-02)[blue] 
if (between=2012-05-14 and 2012-05-21)[blue] 
% GROUP 3
if (between=2012-11-02 and 2012-11-09)[darkgreen] 
if (between=2012-01-01 and 2012-01-27)[darkgreen] 
;


\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: I forget to type "month list". I'm using ConTeXt  ver: 2014.12.06 14:20 MKIV beta  fmt: 2014.12.8  int: english/english, luatex beta-0.7.9.1

Answer (score 2):

This was a bug in PGF which is going to be fixed in a future version.  You can see the fix in this commit:

https://sourceforge.net/u/hmenke/pgf/ci/fcba5723f1e96979942c11286f1f4d6e84355610/